# Find a continuous function to satisfy differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been working through differential equations in the textbook and have come across this example which has really stumbled me. Any advice on how to approach this would be great. Thanks

Find a continuous function $y\colon[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R} $ with $y(0)=9$, that is differentiable on both $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $(\frac{\pi}{4},\infty)$ with derivative $y'(x)$ satisfying the differential equation:
$$y'(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      2xy(x)+e^{x^2}\tan(x), & x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{4}), \\
      \sin^3(x)\cos^2(x),  & x>\frac{\pi}{4}.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What did you tried? What do you know about Heavise function?

Comment: I have never heard of Heavise function

Comment: Probably means the Heaviside unit jump function. In the second case, is the last really an $x$, or was an $y$ intended? Note that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$.

Comment: Ahhh ok and ahh thanks that was a typo -Lutz Lehmann

Answer (score 1):

Roadmap:

1. Solve the IVP $y' = 2xy + e^{x^2} \tan x, \quad y(0)=9$. You'll get
   $y(x) = -e^{x^2} (\log (\cos (x))-9)$. This is the solution on the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$.
2. Compute $y_*= y(\frac{\pi}{4}) = -e^{\frac{\pi ^2}{16}} \left(-9-\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)$
3. Solve the IVP $y'=\sin^3 x \cos^2 x, \quad y(\frac{\pi}{4}) = y_*$. This is the solution on the interval $(\frac{\pi}{4}, +\infty)$.

Can you spot $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in the graphic?

[image]

Comment: i have done steps 1 and 2 slightly struggling with 3 but I want to ask how does this result in finding a function for the answer do I have to add parts 1 and 3 together?

Comment: The final solution is a function defined in branches. The value is given by the result in 1. for $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and by the result obtained in 3. for $x> \frac{\pi}{4}$.